# Story about aliens capturing human soldiers, medically altering and interrogating them

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

This book features graphic and grisly descriptions of aliens capturing human soldiers in battle, removing their eyes and limbs, keeping them alive and probing their brains for information.

I can't remember what book this is from. It's possible I've gotten some of the details wrong over the years. If you do know the book, a chapter number or page number would be great.

Comment: Your question seems to be awfully broad - do you think you could specify a little more, asking perhaps for the book instead and try to clarify a little more?  Thanks (I don't want to sound too harsh as I know it can be difficult remembering all this stuff!)

Comment: @N.Soong You mean there's more than one story where aliens remove soldiers' eyes and limbs and endlessly pump them for information?  I guess I haven't been visiting the right shelves in the library... then again maybe I have been.

Comment: @KyleJones although I expect there would indeed be multiple books about that subject matter, the information provided does seem to be rather scarce, so I'm just asking for more if possible.

Comment: @user14111 - it's not closed, it's on hold. Precisely because the SE mechanics is that "on hold" means it's temporarily being held as being in need of improvement

Comment: I don't think more information is needed.  A plot summary isn't always necessary, and often it only confuses the issue with misremembered details.  A good story identification question spells out what was unique about the story, be it theme, plot detail, or evoked mood.  I think this question has enough detail to be identified by someone who has read the story.  Right now should that person come along they cannot provide an answer because the question is closed to answers.